# sql can information_schema or sys.objects return table object from parameter

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, information-schema

I have a procedure which accepts table name as parameter. My requirement is to find if object exists in information_schema or sys.object (which ever is efficient) and then return the table rows.

is it possible to return complete table object this way?

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(250)
set @tableName = N'Person';
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table Exists';
    SELECT * from @tableName;
END
```

Basically I want to store this result in a temporary table and then update and delete records from there. My code to store in temp table is:

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(4000);
SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tblName;

    PRINT @sqlQuery;
    insert INTO #TempTable 
       EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
    SELECT * FROM #TempTable;
```

I get error on last line saying `#TempTable undefined.`

Comment: You can't use variable as a table name, you'll have to do it with sp_executesql or exec

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL like `EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + quotename(@tableName));`

Comment: This way I am not able to store the result in temp table. I updated my question. please have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery nvarchar(max);
declare @tableName sysname;

set @tableName = N'Person';

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @tableName)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table Exists';

    SET @sqlQuery = N'SELECT * INTO #temp FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N'; '
                  + N' SELECT * FROM #temp;'  

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
END
```

Comment: it returns the result but the issue is I still can't do separately `SELECT * FROM #temp;`. Its important that I can hold value in separate table as when I go to update the table, I can add joins on this temp table. Is there any other way I can pass this data to temp table?